# What is query plan?

Tags: sql, query-optimization

What is it used for? And how it work?

Comment: Please comment this..

Comment: a good tutoriAL TO START WITH http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/285/query-execution-plans/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a video about a query execution plan:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lH2_SI04PWQ

You use it for know what sql are doing and in which order. So you can optimaize your query.